# Can't get content of <tbody> when parsing HTML in Perl

Tags: html, perl, html-tableextract, html-treebuilder

I HAVE SOLVED THIS:Turns out the page I was loading with WWW::Mechanize uses AJAX to load all the content that is inside the `<tbody>` so it is not loaded when I created the $html variable.
Now I must see how to get this dynamic content...

---

I am trying to parse through the content of a table in a webpage. The `<table>` contains a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>`. When I go to get the content from the `<tbody>` part of the table I find that none of it is there. I only get the content that is inside the `<thead>`.

I have tried a few different methods as follow all of which just give me nothing from inside the `<tbody>`.

using HTML::TreeBuilder

```
my $tb = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
$tb->parse($html);
my $table = $tb->look_down( _tag => 'tbody', id => 'tbody-id' );
```

using HTML::TableExtract

```
my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( attribs => { id => 'table-id' } );
$te->parse($html);
my $table=$te->first_table_found;
```

when I try to do a `print Dumper($table);` of of the table I am showing that I am finding the `<table>` and can only see the table content inside of the `<thead>` or the `<tbody>` and a reference to it's parent that contains all the content from `<thead>`.

I could care less about the content in `<thead>` I just need the table content out of `<tbody>`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and where to go from here.

Comment: How about `HTML::TableContentParser`?

Comment: HTML::TableContentParser using `my $tcp = HTML::TableContentParser->new( );
my $tables = $tcp->parse($html);` will grab everthing in `<thead>` and save them as headers but nothing from `<tbody>` ends up in the rows

Answer (score 1):

Is the HTML valid?  It took me a few minutes to get the following code working because I'd not properly closed one of the tags:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Perl6::Say;

my $html = << 'HTML';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <caption>Caption</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Body</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
HTML

my $tree    = HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse_content($html);
my $table   = $tree->look_down('_tag', 'table');
my $caption = $table->look_down('_tag', 'caption');
my $thead   = $table->look_down('_tag', 'thead');
my $tbody   = $table->look_down('_tag', 'tbody');

say $caption->as_HTML;
# <caption>Caption</caption>

say $thead->as_HTML;
# <thead><tr><th>Header</th></tr></thead>

say $tbody->as_HTML;
# <tbody><tr><td>Body</td></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for the answer helps be get a better idea of how it in theory would work.
Turns out the page I was loading with WWW::Mechanize uses AJAX to load all the content that is inside the `<tbody>` so it is not loaded when I created the $html variable.
Now I must see how to get this dynamic content...

Comment: Getting generated content could be tricky - you essentially need a JavaScript engine (e.g., a browser).  You could have a look at [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Selenium), or perhaps even [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino).